# how should you cancel an NSInvocationOperation so that your code stops?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I have a background thread that goes off to a server and gets XML which then renders it to a graph.

I have an `NSTimer` which fires off a request every 5 seconds, what is typically the best way to stop the execution of a thread altogether (if at all possible), I know you can subclass NSInvocationOperation and implement the cancel method, but I dont know what exactly to do, other that put `if (hasBeenCancelled) return;` statements everywhere throughout the code...